# Is this Stokes problem well-posed?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I am solving Stokes problem:
$$\begin{gathered}
\nabla p = \mu \Delta \vec{u} + \vec{f}
\\
\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = 0
\end{gathered}$$
in a  domain that's bounded by two surfaces - a cuboid and a small sphere inside it.

Is this problem well-posed?

If boundary conditions are required, they are: $\vec{u}=u_1 (z-z_0) \vec{e}_x$ (shear flow) on the cuboid and $\vec{u}=\vec{0}$ (stationary) on the sphere.

The geometry looks like this:
[image: A picture of the geometry]

This question follows [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397644/existence-and-uniqueness-of-stokes-flow/412701). I got the conditions but I have no idea how to apply them in this case. As far as I understand, this domain is not really smooth, but does it instantly make this problem ill-posed?

Comment: What is $mu$? and is the body force zero? What is $z_0$? is $z_0$ the $z$-coordinate of the center of the sphere?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao $\mu$ is dynamic viscosity (a variable constant). If this can't be solved for arbitrary body force, assume zero. $z_0$ is some $z$-coordinate, it should remain arbitrary if possible. Otherwise assume any.